# GAMM with multiple and crossed random effects

Tags: modeling, random-effects-model, generalized-additive-model, gamm4

I am new to Generalized additive mixed models (GAMM) and I'm trying to model a behavioral response variable (time spent shading eggs by a nesting bird in minutes `timeCS`) in relation to several predictor variables: maximum temperature (`maxT`), species (`categorical`), the day of the year (`jdate`) and the age of the nest (`ca`). My data was based on repeated observations at several nests of shorebirds.

I have three random effects: nest id (`nest`), location (`rm`) and `year`. Nest is nested within `rm` and `year`; while `rm` and `year` are crossed.

Since I have multiple random effects, I plan to use `gamm4` in R as my software package to  conduct the GAMM. So far I believe the correct code to run this analysis with my data is

```
 gamm4 <- (timeCS~s(maxT)+ species + s(jdate) + s(ca), 
           random=~(1|year)+(1|rm)+(1|rm:nest)+(1|year:nest), 
           data=Dataset, family=gaussian(link ="identity"))
```

Is this correct? Should I specify smooth terms for my predictor variables? Can I run model selection based on AICc on GAMM?

Comment: I have the same question - did you feel this was the correct model specification for your random effects?

Comment: "Can I run model selection based on AICc on GAMM" in general, using the cross-validation error that AIC (sometimes) approximates would be better

Answer (score 0):

Specifying random effect terms in gamm4 is different to mgcv. The syntax I show is provided [in this book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Data-Analysis-statistical-Software-Scientists-ebook/dp/B014RIJBFA).

Two random effect terms in gamm4 is:

```
random = ~(1|xr1 + 1|xr2)
```

If they are nested, it is:

```
random = ~(1|xr1/xr2)
```